# Youtube Data API - Access to Members list is needed

Tags: youtube-api

According to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members, I should to request additional access for endpoint which returns the list of members (sponsors) of my Youtube channel.

The question is how I can do it? Is there some special google form for that? Or maybe some email address? Could you please help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for your query? Any input would be valuable. Thank you!

Comment: @SlickSlime unfortunately no :( I filled out a couple of google forms and emailed Youtube support asking to provide an access to sponsors endpoint. Silence in response…